# Not getting column names whose values are null in DB JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa-2.0

Here i am working on `SQL Server` ,where i am using stored procedure to find data of a user which consist firstname ,lastname ,passwrd etc.

i am using `JPA 2.0` in `Netbeans` ,I created a api which is going to call that procedure and fetch the data .

If a user dont have last name as NULL in DB, JPA not returning the column name as well.

Here my requirement is that if value is null then also it provide column name with null value .

I am using Facade class with entity created from Database .
What I want

```
"Produ": [
        {
            "productPhotoID": 1,
            "largePhotoFileName": null,
            "modifiedDate": "Apr 30, 2008 12:00:00 AM"
        }
```

What i am getting

```
"Products": [
        {
            "productPhotoID": 1,
            "modifiedDate": "Apr 30, 2008 12:00:00 AM"
        }
```

Comment: Are those json results? this looks more like problem with dto serialization.

Comment: @Michal No i dont think so bcoz when we create facade class it automatically implements serializable . Can you brief me more on this.

Comment: I would expect you read your entities from DB, these entities serialized/marshalled to json and that is what you posted here. I would assume that in the object the property largePhotoFileName  has null value and when marshalled to json it is simply omitted

Comment: Value of largePhotoFileName in my DB is null but i am not getting null value ,instead it is not displaying column name.